# Declare optional Event callback in Typescript React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How to define optional callback for Events in React Typescript?

```
interface Props{
    data: any
    handleClick?: ()=>void
}

const FunctionalComponent: React.StatelessComponent<Props> = (props) => {

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {props.data}
            <div onClick={() => props.handleClick()}>optional Click Event</div>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

And class where i use this component:

```
   class HandlerComponent extends React.Component<Props, State>{
        constructor(props){
            super(props)
                this.state = {
                     data: this.props.data
                }
            }
            render() {
                return (
                    <React.Fragment>

                        <FunctionalComponent data={this.state.data} />

                    </React.Fragment>
                )
            }
        }
```

I have error at onClick={() => props.handleClick()} :

```
[ts] Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is that since the property is optional (and you have `strictNullChecks` enabled) Typescript will force you to make sure the `handleClick` is actually not undefined.

The simplest solution is to do the check, using the `&&` operator for example:

```
    <React.Fragment>
        {props.data}
        <div onClick={() => props.handleClick && props.handleClick()}>optional Click Event</div>
    </React.Fragment>
```